# Subdomain DNS isn't working

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, web-hosting, domain-name

I have a domain registered with Godaddy. It has a wildcard CNAME for "www". I have tried to make a sudbomain: mysubdomain.mysite.com.

However the external DNS doesn't seem to be routing at all.

IN IIS, I simply have a binding with: "www.mysubdomain.mysite.com", all IPS.

Do I need to set up explicit cname entries for each subdomain?

Comment: Are you having problems with lookups to `mysubdomain.mysite.com`, or to `www.mysubdomain.mysite.com`?

Comment: So, you've set up `*.mydomain.com` to point to `www.mydomain.com`?

Comment: So looks like my setting are: 1. wild card A record to my IP. 2. wild card cname to "www". host. I'm having trouble with both, but I'm only expecting "www" to work because, thats what my IIS binding is.

Answer (score 1):

The is because [a restriction on CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record),

> An alias defined in a CNAME record must have no other resource records
>   of other types (MX, A, etc.)

and according to [RCF1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt)

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present;
>   this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot
>   be different. This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be used
>   without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

So all your subdomain records should not work.

Comment: So how do I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to just add an explicit A record for the exact subdomain, (despite the fact that the  wildcard was there)